# Javascript Mouseup / Touchend eventListener Variable Undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, addeventlistener

I am trying to attach a mouseup / touchend event listener to a div element in javascript. I would like to pass a variable (or two) with the event, but the variable keeps coming back as undefined.

A function to receive the variable

```
function test(e) {

var to = e.target.var1;

alert(to);

e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
```

Code to add the listener

```
var addEvent = document.getElementById( "testIdDiv" );
addEvent.addEventListener("mouseup", test, false);
addEvent.addEventListener("touchend", test, false);
addEvent.var1 = 'testVar';
```

The variable keeps coming back as
    undefined

What methods could I use debug this problem? I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.

I also tried attaching the variable with

```
addEvent.setAttribute("var1", "testVar");
```

But it made no difference. I have also tried wrapping all the code in try blocks but it doesn't throw any errors other than the undefined variable. Are there any other steps I could take to try and isolate my error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor to this

```
function test(e) {

var to = document.getElementById("testIdDiv").var1;

alert(to);

e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
```

Comment: That just returns the HTMLDivElement object, and not the variable attached to the event...

Comment: I forgot the ".var1"

Comment: Thanks for the update. The issue with this method is that the function may be attached to more than one div. So i'm not sure how your method would know which div is calling the function, and in-turn which div id to fetch.